# Unit testing ControllerFactory.CreateController : This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase

Tags: unit-testing, invalidoperationexception

I have a test class . And inside this , i have  a private class

```
class ControllerProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{    
   public IController CreateController()
   {

   }    
}
```

Inside `CreateController()`, I have created a Mock RequestContext (`mockRequestContext`) and a Test Controller named "TestController"

However, on calling

```
var controller = 
 controllerFactory.CreateController(mockRequestContext.Object, "TestController");
```

I am getting an `InvalidOperationException`:

> "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start
>   initialization phase".

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How implementation of `CreateController` method looks like?